# Content Slider with Zoom feature

Tags: jquery, html, slider

Not sure if this is the right place to ask. but is there any plugin or script that i could use to emulate the slider below link:

http://www.lasoo.com.au/catalogue/summer-hotties/54r4fwrtj.html?pid=promotedCatalogue#pageNo=0

basically i need to be able to slide between multiple pages, show a zoom view via a lightbox and pan through it.

I've tried few items like [JSSlider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/)

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to have written a plugin to do this. It's available on [github](https://github.com/huba/jquery-slideshow). For the usage example look under `tests/carousel.html`. It can't do the zoom-view, but it should be possible to make a button that changes the class of the container and give it a different style with CSS.